# What is the component for the messaging system?

Tags: ros, messages, git, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to have a close look at the messaging i.e. how ROS sends messages from publishers to subscribers. For that I would like to have a look in the code. What is the component that represent the messaging transport system that ties together publishers and subscribers? Where do I find the code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198729/what-is-the-component-for-the-messaging-system?/) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start by looking at the publisher and subscriber classes within roscpp and rospy, and dig into the supporting packages from there.

Most packages provide an auto-generated source link on their wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp . For roscpp, the code is in [ros_comm/clients/roscpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/indigo-devel/clients/roscpp)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2014-12-02**:
Thanks the pointer to roscpp gave me a good starting point.